# Javascript Loop Delay needed

Tags: javascript, for-loop, delay

I Need 3 second delay after 2nd loop. place is commented out. pleaes help.

```
var x = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11,12,13,14],[15,16,17,18,19,20,21],[22,23,24,25,26,27,28],[29,30,31,32,33,34,35],[36,37,38,39,40,41,42],[43,44,45,46,47,48,49]];
var j=indx='';
var n = 7;
var slice = j= indx='';
for (slice = 0; slice < 2 * n - 1; ++slice) {
    var z = slice < n ? 0 : slice - n + 1;
    for (j = z; j <= slice - z; ++j) {
        indx = x[j][slice - j]-1;
        console.log(indx);
    }
    //window.setTimeout("", 1000);
    //i need delay here.----------------------
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [setInterval(callback, time)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). It's the same as `setTimeout` but function will be called forever.
`clearInterval` should be called with your interval's id to stop execution.
`setInterval` function returns that id

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
    var z = slice < n ? 0 : slice - n + 1;
    for (j = z; j <= slice - z; ++j) {
        indx = x[j][slice - j]-1;
        console.log(indx);
    }
    if(++slice >= 2*n-1)
        clearInterval(intervalId);
}, 3000);
```